# Upload File Error using Java EE

Tags: java, file, upload

The following code is reading an error message.  The Java code, in particular, doesn't seem to be recognized as Java when I type it in.  For example, it doesn't automatically indent.  I am using JavaServer Faces.  Does anyone have an idea about where I am going wrong here?

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2e8b57">
    <table style="width:100%">
<tr> 
    <td colspan="1">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 40%"><img src="image.JPG" width="700" height="550"     
    alt="image2"/></td> 
<td style="width: 40%"><font color="white" size="4"><br><b>text goes here</b><br>
<br>text goes here</font></a></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td colspan="1">
</td>
</tr>

</table>

    <form name="uploadForm" action="index.jsp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form- 
    data">
        <% 
String saveFile = new String();
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0)){
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte(formDataLength[]);
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while(totalBytesRead<formDataLength){
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
totalBytesREad +=byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\n")+10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));

int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("-");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length();
int pos;

pos = file.indexOf("filename=\" ");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos)+ 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos)+ 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos)+ 1;

int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos).getBytes().length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes)).length;
}
}



        %>
        <input type="file" name="file" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

The error log is as follows.  Line 43 is the line that contains <% :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
'[' expected

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of expression

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
')' expected

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
')' expected

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 43 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
not a statement

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
<identifier> expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
<identifier> expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
class, interface, or enum expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>. There are also compilation problems in your JSP (missing parenthesis etc.) that you will need to fix.

Thanks Avijit

Comment: Yes, I was missing the tag mentioned above.  But even when I add it the same errors are produced and the jsp still does not seem to recognize the Java code.

Comment: If you are including the JSF taglibs in the JSP.. ensure that the jars are added to the module. Otherwise, the server will not be able to compile the JSP.

Comment: The taglibs have the jars.  The program worked without errors before I added the code between the form tags (including the tablibs).  Something in between the form tags seems to be causing an issue.  The fact that the Java code does not seem to automatically indent when I type it in suggest to me that for some reason it is not being recognized as Java.  But why that would be the case I have no idea.

Comment: I tried it again but in a Java Spring application.  The same code worked there.  But thanks for being the only one to even attempt to help me.